# How to replicate data between tables on linked servers?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linked-server

Good Day

I have created a linked server on my SQL Server to my MySQL Database. The SQL Server Database is Called Main and the Table I am looking at is called ORDR. The MySQL Linked server connection is called MySQL_Link and the table I use in there is also called ORDR. How do I replicate the data from the SQL Server ORDR Table to The MYSQL ORDR table?

Thanks

Comment: cant you write a stored procedure and have it scheduled to check for new data?

Comment: Do you have a field that you can use to identify the rows that are on the source but not the target? If so is it indexed?

Comment: there is a column called ID that can be used to check of it exists in both tables, but I don't know how to refer or sync the data from SQL Server database to the Linked server.